# Normalize columns in a numpy array- results in typeerror

Tags: python, typeerror, normalize

want to do a simple normalization of the data in a numpy ndarray.
specifically want X-mu/sigma.  Tried using the exact code that
that I found in earlier questions - kept getting error = TypeError
cannot perform reduce with flexible type.  Gave up and tried a simpler 
normzlization method X-mu/X.ptp - got the same error.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import urllib.request

#Import comma separated data from git.hub
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-
databases/wine/wine.data'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'F:/Python/Wine Dataset/wine_data')

#open file
filename = 'F:/Python/Wine Dataset/wine_data';
raw_data = open(filename,'rt');

#Put raw_data into a numpy.ndarray
reader = csv.reader(raw_data);
x = list(reader);
data = np.array(x)

#First column is classification, other columns are features
y= data[:,0];
X_raw = data[:,1:13];

# Attempt at normalizing data- really wanted X-mu/sigma gave up
# even this simplified version doesn't work 
# latest error is TypeError cannot perform reduce with flexible type?????

X = (X_raw - X_raw.min(0)) /  X_raw.ptp(0);

print(X);

#
#
#
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  The line "data = np.array(x)" returned an array containing string data.

was:
data = "np.array(x)"

changed to: "np.array(x).astype(np.float)"

after that everything worked - simple issue cost me hours